# ASP .NET MVC 5 legacy url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have to redirect old url (from a Classic Asp website) to the new ones generated using ASP .NET MVC. Example:

From `localhost/news.asp` to `localhost/News`

I addend the following rule:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
            "legacyUrl1",
            "{controller}.asp/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "News", action = "RedirectLegacyURL", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );

//in news controller
 public void RedirectLegacyURL(string id)
    {
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", "news/" );
        Response.End();
    }
```

But the rules "it uses" is the following:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "Normal",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
        );
```

How is this possible? This thing causes problem when I have to redirect legacy urls with query string.

Comment: FWIW, it's better to handle this via IIS, since what's going on in some legacy application is not the domain of your application. It should only be concerned with what it needs, not some legacy app. Use the URL Rewrite module in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

```
routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("", "news.asp")).To(routes.Map("", "Home/Index", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }));
```

This is how I redirect my old .asp routes

Comment: You forgot to specify that this `Redirect` extension method is part of RouteMagic library developped by Phil Haack long time ago. https://github.com/haacked/routemagic And in order to use it OP has to install the following nuget package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/RouteMagic.Mvc/